# unresolved reference: text - Android Studio + Kotlin (findViewById fault?)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to create an alert dialog although I have a very strange problem. My .text is giving me the error "unresolved reference". I triple and quadra checked but cant really find the reason.

Here is the code:

```
fun addChannelClicked(view: View) {
    if (AuthService.isLoggedIn) {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_channel_dialog, null)

        builder.setView(dialogView)
                .setPositiveButton("Add") { dialogInterface, i  ->
                    // perform some logic when clicked
                    val nameTextField = dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.addChannelNameTxt)
                    val descTextField = dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.addChannelDescTxt)
                    val channelName = nameTextField.text.toString()
                    val channelDesc = descTextField.text.toString()

                    // Create channel with the channel name and description
                    hideKeyboard()

                }
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialogInterface, i ->
                    // Cancel and close the dialog
                    hideKeyboard()
                }
                .show()
    }
}
```

Comment: The code seems to be correct. You may put your cursor on `nameTextField` and press `Ctrl+Q` to see if it is `EditText`.

Comment: apparently is a problem with findViewById, but I dont know how to replace this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoul always check if the value is null. It can be done using `if(yourvar != null)` and kotlin will autocast to not-null type in the following lines. You can also use the elvis operator (`?:`) to reach this.

```
val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_channel_dialog, null) ?: return
```

this will ensure that you are returning a not-null instance fro the view or exit from the fuction if not. and then you can call safelly:

```
val nameTextField = dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.addChannelNameTxt)
```

---

The use `!!` operator is not recommened, from the [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator):

> The !! Operator is for NPE-lovers.

Comment: always check when I say the root is null?
just want to make sure I udnerstand what I am doing :)

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: "You shoul always check if the value is null".
You mean I should check every time my root is null?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this kind of syntax

```
 val nameTextField = dialogView!!.findViewById(R.id.addChannelNameTxt) as EditText
```

Comment: Definitely don't use the `!!` syntax.

Comment: @MarošŠeleng Android studio suggest this. Shall I use ? syntax

Comment: @EduardoGuterres this is kotlin syntax. Nothing else. Please put green tick for this answer

Comment: @RanjithKumar cant I take out the !! ?

Comment: @EduardoGuterres  if you take out --> surround with if(dialogView !=null). Another null avoiding syntax also there. I will update later

Answer (score -1):

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.your_layout_xml_name.*

Please replace "your_layout_xml_name" with your "layout_name" on the import line will solve your problem.

Comment: No, actually this line import all view ids for that particular layout, by using this line you don't have to even use findViewById.